# PHP: preg_match() not correct

Tags: php, regex, simplexml, domdocument, docx

I have the following string:

```
<w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="exact"/>
    <w:ind w:left="1890" w:firstLine="360"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
        <w:color w:val="00000A"/>
        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
```

and I am trying to parse the "w:sz w:val" value using preg_match().

So far, I've tried:

```
preg_match('/<w:sz w:val="(\d)"/', $p, $fonts);
```

but this has not worked, and I'm unsure why?

Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have looked at that a little bit.  Do you know of any other PHP libraries or packages that convert docx xml to html?

Comment: Never used it but here's one: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: @jldavis76 Have a look at my answer with `DomDocument` and `SimpleXML` below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were trying to capture only single-digit numbers. Try adding a + to make "one or more".

```
preg_match('/<w:sz w:val="(\d+)"/', $p, $fonts);
```

I prefer [0-9]+ for easier reading, and because it avoids the potentially funny need to double-up on \ symbols.

```
preg_match('/<w:sz w:val="([0-9]+)"/', $p, $fonts);
```

Comment: You, sir, are amazing.  That was exactly the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

While you have a working code at hand, there are two other possibilities, namely with `DomDocument` and `SimpleXML`. This is somewhat tricky with the colons (aka namespaces) but consider the following examples. I have added a container tag to define the namespace but you will definitely have one in your xml as well.
Solution 1 (the `DOM` way) searches the DOM with a namespace prefix and reads the attributes. Solution 2 (with `SimpleXML`) does the same (perhaps in a more intuitive and comprehensible way).

**The XML:** (using PHP HEREDOC Syntax)

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container xmlns:w="http://example">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="exact"/>
        <w:ind w:left="1890" w:firstLine="360"/>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b/>
            <w:color w:val="00000A"/>
            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
</container>
EOF;
```

**Solution 1:** Using DomDocument

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$ns = 'http://example';

$data = $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'sz')->item(0);
$attr = $data->getAttribute('w:val');
echo $attr; // 24
```

**Solution 2:** Using SimpleXML with Namespaces

```
$simplexml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$namespaces = $simplexml->getNamespaces(true);
$items = $simplexml->children($namespaces['w']);

$val = $items->pPr->rPr->sz["val"]->__toString();
echo "val: $val"; // val: 24
```

Comment: That definitely looks interesting.  When I try the second solution, I am get an error:  Message: Trying to get property of non-object.  Any idea why?

Comment: @jldavis76 You could use `var_dump($items);` to see if the items are found in the first place. Remember, this only works with **my** xml at the moment as I have made up a namespace. You will have to use your own, obviously.

Comment: I guess I'm just a little unfamiliar with the use of namespaces in this aspect.  I'll have to look into it more.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a little correction to your regex:

```
<w:sz w:val="(\d)+"
```

So it goes:

```
preg_match('/<w:sz w:val="(\d+)"/', $p, $fonts);
```

Why? Because with just **\d** you are checking for 1 digit, but with **\d+** you are checking for 1 or more.

**EDIT:**

In case you need it, there are some great regex online testing tools, like https://regex101.com/. Try your expressions there before using them, just in case. You never know ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're right! I'll correct it right away.